# 64 Bit App showing "No Source Available"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've turned my 32 bit app into a 64 bit app (all configuration settings are exactly the same and not platform specific).

When running the app, in my main file, both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions debug correctly, however when i step into a function, for Win32, the debugger works just fine, however for the 64 bit version, i get a No Source Available page with no call stack or anything to go on.

Any ideas? Really need some help right now...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

Enable “Just My Code” in the Debugging options
Disable “Require source files to exactly match the original version”, too
Set “Automatically load symbols for all modules”
Clear the symbol cache

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your 64 bit libraries have pdb files. Start with the library which contains the file  for which the 'No Source Available' is displayed. If it's a 3rd party library, perhaps the 64-bit version wasn't configured to output debugging symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough it was a stack overflow (no pun intended). For some reason in 32 bit mode, it was fine but 64 bit didnt like the amount i was using on my stack :s... weird........